# A difficult 2d trigonometric integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, trigonometric-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following seemingly simple integral - so far, without success:

$$\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{y}\frac{\cos(x-y)}{xy}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}$$

For some $0<a<b$. I've tried to change the order of integration, and integration by parts, but so far, without success. Solutions (also using  $\mathop{\mathrm{Si}}$ & $\mathop{\mathrm{Ci}}$ functions) would be very appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: The first thing I would do is to separate the variables. $$\cos(x-y)=\cos x \cos y + \sin x \sin y$$

Comment: @YuriyS Did that, and wasn't successful.

Comment: If you show some of the intermediate results you obtained, it might help in getting the final solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$\begin{align}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{y}\frac{\cos(x-y)}{xy}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}&=\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\cos(x-y)}{xy}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}\\
&=
\frac{1}{2}\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\cos(x)\cos(y)+\sin(x)\sin(y)}{xy}\mathop{\mathrm{d}x}\mathop{\mathrm{d}y}\\
&=\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right)^2
+\frac{1}{2}\left(\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\right)^2.
\end{align}$$
then take a look to [functions $\mathrm Si$ and $\mathrm Ci$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral).

Comment: Of course! I should've known, since I changed the order of integration, and I saw that symmetry between $x$ and $y$, but didn't think of using it that way. Thanks!

Comment: Robert, could this be used to evaluate a similar integral that has $\sin(x-y)$ instead of $\cos(x-y)$ in the integrand?

Comment: In that case tahat trick does not work because $\sin$ is an odd function and $\int_{a}^{b}\int_{a}^{b}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{xy}dxdy=0$.

Comment: Yes, that what I got. Unfortunately, I had a mistake in my calculations and I need the sine variant of the integrand, so I'll ask a new question. Cheers.